# cleaning a sentence from numbers, signs and other languages

Tags: python, string, nlp, data-cleaning

I have a txt file that contain Japanese sentences. I would like to remove all non Japanese words. Such as numbers, English alphabets or any other non Japanese language, signs, symbols. Is there a quick way to do it? Thanks

```
Hi !こんにちは、私の給料は月額10000ドルです。 XO XO
私はあなたの料理が大好きです
私のフライトはAPX1999です。
私はサッカーの試合を見るのが大好きです。
```

Words to remove :
Hi !
XO XO
10000
APX1999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
import string
s = '''Hi !こんにちは、私の給料は月額10000ドルです。 XO XO
私はあなたの料理が大好きです
私のフライトはAPX1999です。
私はサッカーの試合を見るのが大好きです。
'''
# replace all ascii chars 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
replaced = re.sub(f'[{string.printable}]', '', s)
print(replaced)
```

Output

```
こんにちは、私の給料は月額ドルです。私はあなたの料理が大好きです私のフライトはです。私はサッカーの試合を見るのが大好きです。
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is this:

```py
s = "Hi !こんにちは、私の給料は月額10000ドルです。 XO XO 私はあなたの料理が大好きです私のフライトはAPX1999です。私はサッカーの試合を見るのが大好きです"

no_ascii = ''
for c in s:
    ascii_code = ord(c)
    if ascii_code > 127 or ascii_code == 0:
        no_ascii += c

print(no_ascii)
こんにちは、私の給料は月額ドルです。私はあなたの料理が大好きです私のフライトはです。私はサッカーの試合を見るのが大好きです
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.7+ has the isascii() function for str types. This code will remove ascii characters (not necessarily what is being asked) but may help to suggest a strategy.

```
with open('japanese.txt') as infile:
    print(''.join([c for c in infile.read() if c == '\n' or not c.isascii()]))
```